# ^([0-9])+$ RegEx supports numbers and spaces, but how to support empty lines too?

Tags: regex

The RegEx    ^([0-9])+$   supports numbers and spaces. However, I want it to support empty lines too. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
^([0-9])*$
```

or, more simply:

```
^\d*$
```

`\d` means any digit (0-9). `+` means one or more matches. `*` means zero or more matches.

Comment: @Jonathon `\d` is most certainly *not* Perl specific. I can't claim universal functionality but Perl only? Not a chance. Java, C+, PHP and Python all allow it, just off the top of my head.

Comment: as cletus points out, most programming languages use some form of perl-like notation for digits, spaces, etc. The equivalent in POSIX regexes would be [[:digit:]] I suppose.

Comment: Doesn't `\d*` match zero and thus infinitely?

Answer (score 1):

`^([0-9])*$` Change + to *

Btw your code does not support spaces for adding spaces regex should have [0-9\s]

Answer (score 1):

Also, note that in your original (and the recommendations here), you are making a tagged group of just the first digit.   If you want the entire number in the capture, you need the + (or *) inside the perens:

```
^([0-9]*)$
```

On the other hand, if you don't need a capture, you don't need the perens at all:

```
^[0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

By empty line don't you mean a line with a carriage return? Wouldn't that simply be `^(\d*\s*\n)$`?